# Multiple WHERE IS NOT NULL query return empty line

Tags: mysql, sql, null, where-clause

I try to choose only the rows from my table which contain a value in the columns `name_durchgefuehrt`, `name_abgelehnt` and `name_offen` together with an id.

But the query gives all columns out, not only these with values.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id, name_durchgefuehrt, name_abgelehnt, name_offen 
FROM dashboard 
WHERE 
    name_durchgefuehrt IS NOT NULL  
    AND name_abgelehnt IS NOT NULL  
    AND name_offen IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Yes I know it is an easy question for most of you but I had a false understanding of the value 'Null' and I thought I have to do it like this.

Anyways thank you for all the answers.

Comment: Great. Do you have a question? See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The queries giving you exactly what you asked for. What's the question?

Comment: NULL is different from empty string.

Comment: please add the sample data and expected result.

Comment: Null is not an empty string, thank you! I was wrong.

Comment: don't use my `coalesce`, it's useless, just go for `<> ''` it'll rule out both `''` and `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is not `''` (empty string), it's a special state you can test with `IS NULL`.

But `<> ''` will exclude both `NULL` and `''`

So :

```
SELECT id,name_durchgefuehrt,name_abgelehnt,name_offen 
FROM dashboard 
WHERE 
    name_durchgefuehrt <> '' 
    AND 
    name_abgelehnt <> '' 
    AND 
    name_offen <> ''
```

Comment: Ugh. Why the `COALESCE`? `name_durchgefuehrt <> ''` will not bring back nulls or empty strings.

Comment: @MartinSmith damn, you're right, totally forgot, used `COALESCE` a bit to much recently, updated u_u

Answer (score 1):

You must check if your values is not empty string also,it`s not necessary nulls

Answer (score 1):

I would like to note that a string can also consist of spaces that look empty.  So, a more general way that gets rid of spaces is:

```
SELECT id, name_durchgefuehrt, name_abgelehnt, name_offen 
FROM dashboard 
WHERE TRIM(name_durchgefuehrt) <> '' AND
      TRIM(name_abgelehnt) <> '' AND
      TRIM(name_offen) <> '' IS NOT NULL;
```

Because there are hidden characters, you might want to use regular expressions.  For instance, if you have a set of space characters:

```
SELECT id, name_durchgefuehrt, name_abgelehnt, name_offen 
FROM dashboard 
WHERE name_durchgefuehrt regexp '[^[:space]]' AND
      name_abgelehnt regexp '[^[:space]]' AND
      name_offen regexp '[^[:space]]';
```